# Keep only series with non-unique values in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I have data following the following pattern:

```
uid  result
A    FALSE
A    TRUE
A    FALSE
B    FALSE
B    FALSE
B    FALSE
C    TRUE
C    TRUE
C    TRUE
```

I would like to filter out rows grouped by `uid` for which the value of `result` is always the same. In this following example, rows with `uid = B` and `C` will be filtered out, since their corresponding `result` columns only contain respectively `FALSE` and `TRUE`.

On the contrary, rows with `uid = A` will be kept since it contains both `TRUE` and `FALSE` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
your_data |> filter(n_distinct(result) > 1, .by = uid)
#   uid result
# 1   A  FALSE
# 2   A   TRUE
# 3   A  FALSE
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
your_data = read.table(text = 'uid  result
A    FALSE
A    TRUE
A    FALSE
B    FALSE
B    FALSE
B    FALSE
C    TRUE
C    TRUE
C    TRUE', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```r
dplyr::filter(df, any(diff(result) != 0), .by = uid)
#>   uid result
#> 1   A  FALSE
#> 2   A   TRUE
#> 3   A  FALSE
```